# Issue with subquery in Oracle corrected the query?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT SEC.ERROR_GROUP_ID),
  COUNT(DISTINCT SEC_DET.ERROR_GROUP_ID),
  COUNT(DISTINCT MB.ERROR_GROUP_ID),
  COUNT(DISTINCT OD.ERROR_GROUP_ID),
  (SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT SEC_SCH.ERROR_GROUP_ID)
    FROM SCHEMA.SECURITY SEC
    LEFT OUTER JOIN SCHEMA.SECURITY_SCHEDULE SEC_SCH
     ON SEC.MSD_SECURITY_ID     =SEC_SCH.MSD_SECURITY_ID
     WHERE SEC.MSD_SECURITY_ID IN
      ( SELECT DISTINCT main.MSD_SECURITY_ID
         FROM SCHEMA2.Positions main
          WHERE main.QUANTITY != 0
          AND systimestamp    >= main.eff_from_dt
          AND main.eff_to_dt   > systimestamp
          AND systimestamp    >= main.asrt_from_dt
          AND main.asrt_to_dt  > systimestamp
     )) 

FROM SCHEMA.SECURITY SEC
JOIN SCHEMA.SECURITY_DETAIL SEC_DET
ON SEC.MSD_SECURITY_ID = SEC_DET.MSD_SECURITY_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN SCHEMA.MUNI_BOND MB
ON SEC.MSD_SECURITY_ID=MB.MSD_SECURITY_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN SCHEMA.OPTION_DETAIL OD
ON SEC.MSD_SECURITY_ID =OD.MSD_SECURITY_ID
WHERE SEC.MSD_SECURITY_ID IN
  ( SELECT DISTINCT main.MSD_SECURITY_ID
  FROM SCHEMA2.Positions main
  WHERE main.QUANTITY != 0
  AND systimestamp    >= main.eff_from_dt
  AND main.eff_to_dt   > systimestamp
  AND systimestamp    >= main.asrt_from_dt
  AND main.asrt_to_dt  > systimestamp
  ) ;
```

Error ORA-00936: missing expression
00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"
*Cause:
*Action:
Error at Line: 365 Column: 3

The Nested query syntax needs to b corrected for this to work thats where i am stuck at ?.

Comment: I corrected  the query kindly take a look at the same and this is not a many result issue, I need to get the syntax correct for the query qbove

Answer (score 1):

This is a partial answer - I do not understand fully some of your code.  I think it has issues.,

Note: ** means bold -- I messed up formatting ** is not part of this SQL.

You have to group by something.  In this case:

```
(SELECT DISTINCT (SEC_SCH.ERROR_GROUP_ID)
    FROM SCHEMA.SECURITY SEC
    LEFT OUTER JOIN SCHEMA.SECURITY_SCHEDULE SEC_SCH
     ON SEC.MSD_SECURITY_ID     =SEC_SCH.MSD_SECURITY_ID
     WHERE SEC.MSD_SECURITY_ID IN
      ( SELECT DISTINCT main.MSD_SECURITY_ID
         FROM SCHEMA2.Positions main
          WHERE main.QUANTITY != 0
          AND systimestamp    >= main.eff_from_dt
          AND main.eff_to_dt   > systimestamp
          AND systimestamp    >= main.asrt_from_dt
          AND main.asrt_to_dt  > systimestamp
     )) **foo**

    FROM SCHEMA.SECURITY SEC
    JOIN SCHEMA.SECURITY_DETAIL SEC_DET
    ON SEC.MSD_SECURITY_ID = SEC_DET.MSD_SECURITY_ID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN SCHEMA.MUNI_BOND MB
    ON SEC.MSD_SECURITY_ID=MB.MSD_SECURITY_ID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN SCHEMA.OPTION_DETAIL OD
    ON SEC.MSD_SECURITY_ID =OD.MSD_SECURITY_ID
    WHERE SEC.MSD_SECURITY_ID IN
      ( SELECT DISTINCT main.MSD_SECURITY_ID
      FROM SCHEMA2.Positions main
      WHERE main.QUANTITY != 0
      AND systimestamp    >= main.eff_from_dt
      AND main.eff_to_dt   > systimestamp
      AND systimestamp    >= main.asrt_from_dt
      AND main.asrt_to_dt  > systimestamp
      )
    **group by foo** ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your overall query is an aggregation query without a `group by`, so it would be expected to return one row.  You have a subquery in the `select` that can return multiple rows -- I suspect the problem is related to this structure.

I would suggest that you change the `distinct` to an aggregation function.  But what?  `COUNT(DISTINCT SEC_SCH.ERROR_GROUP_ID))` ?  MAX(SEC_SCH.ERROR_GROUP_ID))`?  LISTAGG(SEC_SCH.ERROR_GROUP_ID, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY SEC_SCH.ERROR_GROUP_ID))`?  I don't know.  It is not clear what you want for the third column.

Your entire query looks suspect.  So many `count(disintct)` expressions often mean that you are joining along independent dimensions -- creating a cartesian product.  Hard to say if that is a problem, because without sample data and desired results, your question doesn't actually say what you want to accomplish.

Comment: I made a mistake i corrected the Original Post to clear the same, I want the counts for several tables based on the LEFT JOINS,